# Jenkins seems to be the target for nohup in a script started via ssh, how can I prevent that?

Tags: unix, ssh, jenkins

I am trying to create a Jenkins job that restarts a program that runs all the time on one of our servers.

I specify the following as the command to run:

```
cd /usr/local/tool && ./tool stop && ./tool start
```

The script 'tool' contains a line like:

```
nohup java NameOfClass &
```

The output of that ends up in my build console instead of in nohup.out, so the job never terminates unless I terminate it manually, which terminates the program.

How can I cause nohup to behave the same way it does from a terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, Jenkins is killing all processes at the end of the build and you would like some process to be left running after the build has finished.

You should read https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Essentially, Jenkins searches for processes with some secret value in BUILD_ID environment variable. Just override it for the processes you want to be left alone.

Comment: Actually the build doesn't terminate until I kill it by clicking the stop icon in Jenkins, it sits there showing me the output from the command that's supposed to be run by nohup.  I'll read the link you posted anyway for background but I'm guessing it solves the opposite problem.

Comment: The BUILD_ID environment variable in that link looks promising.

Comment: Has BUILD_ID stopped working? Tried everything and couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Pipeline jobs, setting `BUILD_ID` no longer prevents Jenkins from killing your processes once the job finishes. Instead, you need to set `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE`:

```
sh 'JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe nohup java NameOfClass &'
```

See [the wiki on ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller) and [this comment in the Jenkins Jira](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28182?focusedCommentId=304426&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-304426) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `&` in the Jenkins build step and redirecting the output using `> nohup.out`.

Comment: Neither of those seemed to help.  nohup implicitly redirects to a file named nohup.out and the line in the script that calls nohup already ends with &

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with runnning a shell script  from jenkins as a background process. I fixed it by using the below command:

**BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup ./start-fitnesse.sh &**

In your case, 
**BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup java NameOfClass &**